# Why was my question downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190668/iphone-device-version-statistics/190673?noredirect=1#190673) was downvoted and closed.

Comments suggested it was downvoted because it was a question about data unrelated to programming. The question it was duped as is a very similar question, why is that one on-topic and mine off?

Also, the question it was closed as a dupe of does ask about device stats, but no answers mention them. It has an accepted answer too, so I'm unlikely to get much help there or have much success reviving it.

Where should I ask this question if not here, or how can I fix it up so that it's acceptable?

Comment: as far as I can tell, the more appropriate closure would be as suggested [in comments](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190668/iphone-device-version-statistics/190673?noredirect=1#comment368447_190668): a duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139377/current-ios-version-device-statistics

Comment: @gnat The answers to that question address only iOS version, and not device version.

Comment: Note to mods:  iOS version is _not_ tied to device version, so neither can be used to fully answer the other.

Answer (score 5):

Your question has several problems.

1. Any answer is highly likely to be outdated five minutes from now.  This is why questions get like this often closed as "Too Localized."
2. The question cannot be answered definitively.  There may be several sources of information out there, or there may be none at all.  If they exist, chances are you would have already found them using Google.  This is why questions like this often get closed as "Not Constructive."
3. You didn't tell us why you need the information, which makes the question further unanswerable because there could possibly be a broad range of statistics to draw from, none of which apply to you.  Telling us what problem you were trying to solve might have evoked a novel solution from someone.  This is why questions like this often get closed as "Not a Real Question."
4. Your question already has coverage here.  This is why questions like this often get closed as duplicates.